# bash source and alias issue

Tags: linux, bash

I have a library file in which I have one alias:

```
$ cat mylib.sh
alias mal='ls -l'

$cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
source mylib.sh
mal

$./test.sh
./test.sh: line 3: mal: command not found
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: aliases are NORMALLY not expanded into non-interactive shells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute an alias in a non-interactive shell, use

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

You might instead want to use functions:

```
mal() { 
    ls -l
}

mal
```

Comment: sorry it is typo! let me fix it.

Comment: there is an alias behind it

Comment: It's possible. In fact, the answer says how in the first sentence.